# preg match for known value plus 7 charecters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Can anyone help me get the value of IFC/USD 0.00001031 from the webpage http://infinitecoin.com.
I need to grab the value after IFC/USD..

The way I thought to do it was to:

```
$file_string = file_get_contents('http://infinitecoin.com');
preg_match('/IFC/USD plus next 11 charecters', $file_string, $title);
$value = $title[1];
echo $title_out ;
```

But im not sure how to ask PHP to find IFC/USD then return the next 11 characters after that.
If I could accomplish this, my task would be solved..
Any help would be great.
Thank you
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = array();

preg_match("/(?<=IFC\/USD\s)[\d\.]+/", 'IFC/USD 0.00001015', $output);
```

$output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.00001015
)
```